# PowerBI Cumulative Total by Month within Year (Financial Year)

Tags: cumulative-sum, powerbi-desktop

I want to plot  cumulative totals (Actual vs Plan) by month within each year (Actually financial year starting in each July). I have the basic cumulative total working across all months- See Figure 1.

But I am struggling to implement a filter that allows users to view the cumulative total for each financial year separately (i.e. with the year starting with a cumulative Actuals and Plans  values being zero).

At the moment - if I select the second financial year with the slicer, the cumulative total doesn't start at zero (See figure 2)[image]

Can anyone suggest a fix?  I am not sure if the solution is linked to the Filter/ Slicer behavior or the DAX calculation.

**Figure 1 : Cumulative totals by month across all years**

[image]

**Figure 2 : Cumulative totals for second Year. Issue as year  doesn't start off with Plans and Actuals being zero**

My current cumulative total calculations (for Actuals & Plan) are here

```
Cumulative Actuals = 

IF (
    MIN ( 'Date Dim'[BOM] )
        <= CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'Detailed Breakdown'[Actuals_BOMS]), ALL ('Detailed Breakdown') ),

CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Detailed Breakdown'[Actual($)]), 
    FILTER (
        ALL ( 'Date Dim'[BOM] ), 'Date Dim'[BOM] <= MAX ( 'Date Dim'[BOM] )
    )
))



Cumulative Plan = 
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Detailed Breakdown'[Plan($)]), 
    FILTER (
        ALL ( 'Date Dim'[BOM] ), 'Date Dim'[BOM] <= MAX ( 'Date Dim'[BOM] )
    )
)
```

A [copy of my PBI file is located here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ah2Oepx2XkEBaYW2rAWQo6yw7CGUGe1g/view?usp=sharing)